# Select one column by two different names in the same query

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named `Main` that contains two fields `id,name`.

I want to select the `name` column by two different names. For example:

**Table Main**

```
id:int, name:varchar(20)
```

I have inserted the following records:

```
id  | name 
----+------- 
  1 | Ahmad 
  2 | Sami
```

I want to select the data like this:

```
select Main.name as n1,Main.name as n2 from Main
where n1='Ahmad' and n2='Sami'
```

When I execute this query, it gives the following error:

> ERROR:  column "n1" does not exist
>   LINE 1: select Main.name n1,Main.name n2 from Main where n1='Ahmad' ...`

I use PostgreSQL as my DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select n1.name as "n1", n2.name as "n2"
 from main n1, main n2
 where n1.name = 'Ahmad'
     and n2.name = 'Sami';
```